# How did Count Duckula's predecessor meet his end?

Tags: vampire, undead, count-duckula

According to [the title narration of the cartoon *Count Duckula* (1988)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9ZVWMPuZ2c),

> Castle Duckula, home for many centuries to a dreadful dynasty of vicious vampire ducks – The Counts of Duckula. Legend has it that these 'fowl' beings can be destroyed by a stake through the heart or exposure to sunlight. This does not suffice however, for they may be brought back to life by means of a secret rite that can be performed once a century, when the moon is in Eighth House of Aquarius.... The latest reincarnation did not run according to plan....

We then are shown that the "current" incarnation of Count Duckula is very un-vampire-like. Due to substitution of tomato ketchup for blood in the reincarnation ritual, the new count is a vegetarian who has little interest in vampire things and can't be bothered to suck anyone's blood.

This narration strongly implies that the immediate predecessor of the current Count Duckula was, in fact, a traditional vampire who most likely met his end in the late 19th century through one of the listed methods.

Is it ever established in the series or in supporting materials how exactly the previous Duckula met his end? Was he staked through the heart? Was he destroyed by sunlight?

In response to comments, whether or not each incarnation is epistemologically the same duck as before is not part of the question. If you feel that there is only a single Duckula and each incarnation is just the same character in a new body, you can interpret the question as "How did the previous incarnation of Duckula meet his end?".

Also in response to comments, this question is not intended to delve into a discussion on what it means for an undead creature to die. For the purpose of this question, assume that any event that requires the vampire to be resurrected by the once-in-a-century ritual (e.g. being staked through the heart or being exposed to sunlight) qualifies as "meeting his end". If specific episodes of the series establish additional ways for an incarnation to be offed (e.g. fire, acid, extreme bowel blockage, etc.), then those methods count for the purposes of this question.

Comment: We see one ancestor get dusted by sunlight in [the intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9ZVWMPuZ2c) — although we also see a hall of portraits, and the one immediately next to our Count doesn't seem to match the sunlight victim's appearance.

Comment: For the record, all of Duckula's "ancestors" are in fact that titular count, reincarnated; "*Each episode is stand alone, and indeed facts can shift from one episode to another depending upon the gag, and concern the Transylvanian vampire duck Count Duckula (David Jason). Duckula’s father (and other forebears) are often mentioned – we even get a sepia flashback to his great-grandfather, but in truth they are all Duckula – he is simply reincarnated.*"

Comment: @Valorum perhaps, but the introduction introduces them as a "dynasty" of "ducks" (plural). Whether or not each incarnation of Duckula is epistemologically the same "person" (or duck) is more a detail. It is quite an interesting question, but it is not the question here. If you feel that all of the incarnations are the same character, you can interpret the question as "How did the previous incarnation of Duckula meet his end?".

Comment: @RobertColumbia - He didn't meet his end. He was temporarily inconvenienced :-)

Answer (score 2):

### The Canon is Unreliable

We see a [similar but more conventionally evil version of Duckula in the original *Danger Mouse* series](https://danmacgregor.fandom.com/wiki/Count_Duckula_(Character)) who is vulnerable to sunlight and is even turned to dust by it on one occasion. *So the previous Count Duckula from Danger Mouse may have been killed before the spin-off, and most likely by sunlight.*

However it is unclear which of his on-screen deaths, if any, were final as [commentators have noted](https://dangermouse.fandom.com/wiki/Count_Duckula) (he's been crushed by an elephant, thrown off a cliff twice, and burnt to a crisp but is up and about by the next scene as if nothing has happened).

It would be logical if the previous incarnation of Duckula in the eponymous *Duckula* series were the antagonist from the *Danger Mouse* series. That would make the incarnation from *Danger Mouse* particularly long-lived, since the vampire duck may on be ***brought back to life by a secret rite that can be performed once a century***.